# Requiring unknown module "607". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting Metro bundler

Tags: react-native

After reload the project in simulator, suddenly I am getting this error again and again:

> Requiring unknown module "607". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting Metro bundler. You may also want to run 'yarn', or 'npm install' (depending on your environment).

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Close all your terminal and restart your simulator and run . run it again it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try clearing the metro cache.  Did you update your package.json or link anything recently?  Try deleting the app on your phone and reinstalling ...  Sorry, I've seen errors like this and I know they can be frustrating!

Comment: I did just quit my simulator & then start it again and it's working.

Comment: Same thing happens. It works after restarting the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to the correct answer, that you should restart terminal AND delete app from simulator or physical device