# Unknown module '1298' in react-native

Tags: react-native

My react-native version is 0.52.During generating the build on actual iOS device I am constantly getting error requiring unknown module '1298'.If you are sure the module is there,try restarting metro bundler.Is there any way to solve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Requiring unknown module "607". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting Metro bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016723/requiring-unknown-module-607-if-you-are-sure-the-module-is-there-try-restart)

Comment: maybe try npm start --reset-cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command: `react-native-link && npx jetify`, and then, try again with `npm start --reset-cache`